# How to speed up mouse events?

Tags: performance-tuning, dynamic, grid-layouts

Grids of dynamic objects responding to mouseovers seem to be quite slow in general, for instance:

```
Grid[Table[
  Mouseover[Framed[" ", Background -> Blue], 
   Framed[" ", Background -> White]], {i, 50}, {j, 50}], 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

How can this lagging be avoided?

Comment: It seems reasonably fast to me; how much lag are you seeing?

Comment: About a second, but If you increase the size of the grid it gets worse fast.

Comment: Okay, if I make the grid bigger, e.g. 150x150 I see the lag.  What is your application for this many Mouseovers?  Perhaps there is a faster approach.

Comment: What platform as you on?  Linux? On a fairly outdated Windows machine I can highlight about 6-8 cells per second.

Comment: I had similar problems: I wanted the user to be able to click on a grid. Solved the problem by having just one click event and determining the bin from the mouse coordinates manually.

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: A strange behavior: if the `Grid` is displayed in it's full width, the mouseover effect is instantaneous. Though if the `Grid` is broken by linebreaks because of a not-wide-enough window, the lagging is apparent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not the Mouseover itself, but with the redrawing of the Framed elements.

This, for example, is much faster:

```
Grid[Table[
  Mouseover[Style[" ", Background -> Blue], 
            Style[" ", Background -> White]], {i, 50}, {j, 50}], Spacings -> 2,
  Frame -> All]
```